# How do I make this code shorter

Tags: java

How do I make this code shorter I have tried everything!

```
if(((condition.toString()).length()) == ("false".length()) - 1&&((condition.toString()).length()) != "true".length() + 1){
            System.out.println("true");
        }
```

Comment: What is `condition` and what, specifically, are you trying to do?

Comment: You could remove some of the excess brackets.

Comment: Pull out `condition.toString().length()` as a variable: `int c = condition.toString().length();`. Then inline the lengths of the strings: `if (c == 4 && c != 5) { ... }`. So, simply: `if (c == 4)`.

Comment: `if (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {` ?

Comment: Sorry fellas, I think this is elaborate trolling, not a real question. The code is just a convoluted way of doing `if(condition)` – it's nearly impossible that anyone could arrive at this version by accident.

Comment: @JJJ it's convoluted, but it's not equivalent to that.

Comment: Not exactly equivalent, but the "joke" implies that `condition` is boolean.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a test question Aaron has been given.

Comment: Not nearly enough in the example code to answer fairly, even if one could take the question seriously.

Answer (score 5):

On the assumption that `condition.toString().length()` is the same both times it is evaluated, pull it out as a variable:

```
int c = condition.toString().length();
```

Then inline the values of `("false".length()) - 1` and `"true".length() + 1`:

```
if (c == 4 && c != 5) { ... }
```

Since 4 != 5:

```
if (c == 4) {
  System.out.println("true");
}
```

If you'd prefer not having the `c` variable:

```
if (condition.toString().length() == 4) {
  System.out.println("true");
}
```

If you are unable to make the assumption about `condition.toString().length()` being the same both times, all you can do is to remove unnecessary parentheses and inline the values of `("false".length()) - 1` and `"true".length() + 1`.

```
if (condition.toString().length() == 4
    && condition.toString().length() != 5) {
  System.out.println("true");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried iterating the code myself to simplify it as -

```
if(((condition.toString()).length()) == ("false".length()) - 1&&((condition.toString()).length()) != "true".length() + 1) {
    System.out.println("true");
}
```

Trimming off the brackets -

```
if ( condition.toString().length() == ("false".length()) - 1 && (condition.toString()).length() != "true".length() + 1) {
        System.out.println("true");
}
```

Replacing the constant values -

```
if ( condition.toString().length() == 4 && (condition.toString()).length() != 5) {
    System.out.println("true");
}
```

As [Suggested by @Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42788939/1746118)

```
int c = condition.toString().length();
if (c == 4) {
    System.out.println("true");
}
```

Simplifying further (note this one handles the `else` part of the condition as well where I'm printing a new line `""`)

```
int c = condition.toString().length();
System.out.println(c==4?"true":"");
```

One liner -

```
System.out.println(condition.toString().length()==4?"true":"");
```

Comment: "Simplifying further" Nope, that's not the same thing.

Comment: @AndyTurner - ya I should mention doing nothing for the else part (Y). I hope that's what you're pointing to as well.

Comment: Reasons to downvote please.

Answer (score -1):

It seems your check can be simplified to this.

```
int c = condition.toString().length();

    if(c == 4){
     ...
}
```

the second check if c!= 5 is unnecessary since if c == 4 it will never equal 5!

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the unnecessary grouping signs, and declare a local variable for the 
condition.toString().length() that you are using the most

```
int condL = condition.toString().length();
if (condL == "false".length() - 1 && condL != "true".length() + 1) {
    System.out.println("true");
}
```